# Bullet points with a quote at the end - period placement

Tags: grammar

Does the period go inside or outside of quotes in a list of bullet points?

Which is correct?

•   Remove reference to “repair” in (a)(2), because “repair” is already encompassed in the word “maintenance”.

•   Remove reference to “repair” in (a)(2), because “repair” is already encompassed in the word “maintenance.”

Comment: The presence of bullet marks is irrelevant. In this case, the quote marks indicate that the word being used is a special context. The period will go outside the quotes.

Comment: As Greybeard says, the bullet point doesn't matter, but as for the period, this is a British/American English difference.  American English always places periods (and commas) always go inside the quotation marks.  In British English, they're placed outside.

Comment: British English does not mandate that the other punctuation mark must go outside the quotes regardless of context. Rather, there is *no* rule mandating a particular order for the quotation mark and the other punctuation mark, an order which must be used regardless of context. In some contexts you have a quotation mark then another punctuation mark. In others, it's the other way around (e.g. when an entire sentence is put in quotation marks).

Comment: I'm with Rosie F, except that there's no such thing as 'British English'. 'The usual practice in the UK is to ...'.

Comment: @Juhasz so the same would be true for a sentence that ends with a special context in quotes? As such:  ...is proposing to utilize the existing definition of “rebarrelling” to better define the term “repair”.

Comment: I typically use the American convention of putting the period inside the quotation marks. However, in contexts where clarity is more important than stylistic correctness (such as a technical specification), I will sometimes put the period outside of the quotation marks. In other words, if I think there's some chance that the period that is meant to end the sentence will be misinterpreted as something else (i.e. a period that's integral to the word or phrase in quotation marks), I would put it outside.